# what this mean : If no model is returned no view is rendered?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

[Spring MVC's documentation states](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-servlet-sequence)

> If a model is returned, the view is rendered. If no model is returned (maybe due to a preprocessor or postprocessor intercepting the request, perhaps for security reasons), no view is rendered, because the request could already have been fulfilled.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

Simply if no value of your view page is returned, maybe is blocked by some security, anything that can block or intercept that response (CSRF for example), IntenalViewResolver will not have anything to render for you.
This further tells you that if a specific @RequestMapping URL does not return a view page value, you will have nothing rendered.
The only way that InternalViewResolver will render a view is in the case when you return a view name and it does not get blocked in that process.